# Syntax for WiFi configuration with proxy settings in Lua scripts

Tags: proxy, lua, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

I trying to code ESP8266 using Lua scripts for connecting with my network. The problem is, My network has proxy settings. I didn't find any syntax in Lua tutorials for coding proxy settings.

The network has

**PROXY**
    Proxy hostname : 
Proxy port :

**IP Settings 
Static**

IP address :
Gateway :
Network length :
DNS 1 :
DNS 2 :

**Edit 1 :**

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("Network_name","password")

print(wifi.sta.getip())

srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
        local buf = "";
        buf = buf.."HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"
        local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
        if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
        end
        local _GET = {}
        if (vars ~= nil)then
            for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
                _GET[k] = v
            end
        end


        client:send(buf);
        client:close();
        collectgarbage();
    end)
end)
```

This code work for network without internet. But I tried to code for the network with proxy settings (proxy hostname,Static IP settings ) which has Internet.

Comment: "connecting with my network" - connecting in which way? You don't need a proxy to connect to the WiFi access point, right? But later (once WiFi is established) you need proxy to send requests to the internet, right?

Comment: I have edited the post, Please check and revert back. @MarcelStör

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. This code creates a _server_ on the device which listens to requests. When you send a request from some client (e.g. browser) that client connects to this server in some way through a proxy or directly. The device doesn't care from where the request was sent. It just sends a HTTP OK back to wherever the request came from. Side note: this isn't a very good example of how to initialise a NodeMCU application, see http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua for a better template.

Comment: wifi.sta.config("Network_name","password") -- this line connect my ESP8266 to the router (No proxy, no IP static's) which is not configured for Internet. Now, I need my ESP to connect to a router which is configured for Internet with proxy, static IP's. @MarcelStör